# Cisco HSRP configuration error in packet tracer

Tags: cisco

When I configure hsrp everything is ok, but when I connect r1 to r2 and r1 to switch2 then comminication stops.
When I remove both the link then again every thing is ok.
password packet tracer is cisco when asked

hsrp ip 172.16.32.3 group number 10

please help so that I am able to confiure the same with both link.

R1

```
Switch>en
Switch>enable
Password:
Password:
Switch#show run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1511 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
enable secret 5 $1$mERr$hx5rVt7rPNoS4wqbXKX7m0
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
switchport access vlan 50
switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
switchport access vlan 50
switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
switchport access vlan 50
switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
!
interface Vlan50
ip address 172.16.32.1 255.255.0.0
standby version 2
standby 10 ip 172.16.32.3
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
line con 0
exec-timeout 0 20
password 7 0822455D0A16
logging synchronous
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
password 7 0822455D0A16
login
!
!
end
```

R2

```
Current configuration : 1324 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
switchport access vlan 50
switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
switchport access vlan 50
switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
!
interface Vlan50
ip address 172.16.32.2 255.255.0.0
standby version 2
standby 10 ip 172.16.32.3
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
login
!
!
end
```

Comment: Please include configurations of all relevant devices. Also, please keep in mind that this is not a site for "please do my work" questions. We can help you if you provide enough details and ask questions which show that you've put effort into solving your problems.

Comment: Also, please don't type your entire message in caps.

Comment: here is my configuration

Comment: Are you trunking VLANs between switches?  Are the VLANs enabled on both switches?

Comment: Those configurations are for switches, not routers, and you have not enabled routing if they are layer-3 switches. Also, the two switches must be connected on that VLAN in order to exchange HSRP messages.